# Can i modify the X-axises Date formate and the font width for the tooltips for my Jqplt Data plot chart in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqplot

i have the following data points jqplot chart in my asp.net mvc:-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var line1 = [['23-May-2008', 578.55], ['20-Jun-2008', 566.5], ['25-Jul-2008', 480.88], ['22-Aug-2008', 509.84], ['26-Sep-2008', 454.13], ['24-Oct-2008', 379.75], ['21-Nov-2008', 303], ['26-Dec-2008', 308.56], ['23-Jan-2009', 299.14], ['20-Feb-2009', 346.51], ['20-Mar-2009', 325.99], ['24-Apr-2009', 386.15], ['01-Apr-2012', 786.15]];
        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], { title: 'Data Point Highlighting',
            axesDefaults: { pad: 1.2 },
            axes: { xaxis: { renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer },
                yaxis: { tickOptions: { formatString: '%.2f'} }
            },
            highlighter: { show: true, sizeAdjust: 7.5, tooltipLocation: 'nw' }, cursor: { show: true, tooltipOffset: 6 }
        })

    });

</script>
```

1. But can i change the date format for both the x- axises and the tooltip to be something like 15 Feb 2005 instead of the current format as 15/02/2005.

2.second question is there a way to change the format for the tooltip to be bold.

BR

Comment: If you got an answer to your question, please make sure you'll accept it by clicking on the checkmark. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, add this `tickoptions` to the `xaxis` brackets:

   ```
   xaxis:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions:{
                          formatString:'%d/%b/%Y'
                        } 
         },
   ```
2. Yes, add `formatString` option to the `highlighter` bracket:

   ```
   highlighter:{
                show: true,
                sizeAdjust: 7.5,
                tooltipLocation: 'nw',
                formatString:'<b>%s</b>'
                },
   ```

Comment: thanks for the reply,,, actually the date format worked fine ,, but regarding the second point when i added "formatString:'<b>%s</b>'", then the tooltip will only display the date without the y-axis value.